# Синонимизировать все виды [кэширование] и [cache]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки:

- [кэширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (81 вопрос)
- [кеширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (36 вопросов)
- [cache](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cache) (121 вопрос)
- [кэш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88) (22 вопроса)

так как это одно и то же.

Основной меткой сделать [кэширование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Comment: Уверены, что все посетители, интересующиеся *кэшированием*, смогут правильно написать (а то и просто распознать) `cache`?

Comment: Так сделать `cache` синонимом кеширования.

Comment: И  что будет отображаться в итоге в метках вопроса?

Comment: У текущих? Или у новых? Для текущих можно оставить как есть, там сработает редирект.

Comment: А что будет у новых?

Comment: Когда они начнут вводить метку `cache`, то им покажут тег `кэширование`.

Comment: Тогда сгодится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пока не пнёшь — не полетит](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41569794#41569794). Готово.